# Can the IMF technically kick Russia out of the organization?

Tags: russian-federation, international-monetary-fund

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Monetary_Fund

> Voting power in the IMF is based on a quota system. Each member has a
> number of basic votes (each member's number of basic votes equals
> 5.502% of the total votes),[113] plus one additional vote for each special drawing right (SDR) of 100,000 of a member country's
> quota.[114] The special drawing right is the unit of account of the
> IMF and represents a potential claim to currency. It is based on a
> basket of key international currencies. The basic votes generate a
> slight bias in favour of small countries, but the additional votes
> determined by SDR outweigh this bias.[114] **Changes in the voting
> shares require approval by a super-majority of 85% of voting
> power.[11]**

I couldn't find anything about the rights of kicking Russia, but it seems to suggest that changing the voting shares of Russia to zero, which is technically the same as kicking it from the organization, would require a super-majority of 85%, so I am assuming that Russia could be kicked out of the organization if a super-majority decides to do so. Is that so, or there's a provision in the laws that prevents that from happening?

Comment: Quite unlike to happen due to China, India, Pakistan, South Africa, etc. I'm pretty sure non-Western countries sufficiently friendly to Russia have more than 15% shares at IMF. It's also not terribly clear what practical goal could be achieved by kicking Russia out. IMF lending them money requires more than 15% votes approval, I'm sure.

Comment: @Fizz Pakistan is in the US sphere of influence so perhaps not them. In fact, a lot of countries receive financial aid from the US so their votes are essentially pre-purchased.

Comment: Anyone who wants to read these ought to be able to write an answer: [Articles of Agreement of the International Monetary Fund](https://www.imf.org/external/pubs/ft/aa/index.htm).

Comment: @uberhaxed: Pakistan mostly votes how China does in international bodies, like the UN https://yiqinfu.github.io/posts/united-nations-general-assembly/

Comment: @Fizz Depends on which faction is ruling there, but China defenetly has influence on Pakistan.